# no border radius in IE8, css3PIE not working?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, css, css3pie

I see there are many variations of this question but none of my attempts have worked.

I would like to get rounded corners in IE8 as I do in Firefox, Chrome... here is my css, after downloading css3PIE:

```
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px;
behavior:url(/PIE.php);
position:relative;
z-index: 0;
```

I swapped out 'PIE.php' with 'PIE.htc', with no effect.  My html index file is in the same directory as the PIE files and the css sheet. I tried adding the z-index and position rules based on posts I saw here, but no effect there either.  I tried simply PIE.htc and PIE.php as a path as well, but no luck...

Is there something else I can do, or is something wrong here?
Thanks, Jason

Comment: `My html index file is in the same directory as the PIE files and the css sheet.` is that the domain's root directory? Because that's what you're pointing to with the leading `/`. If you want to target the *current* directory, use `behaviour:url(PIE.php)` also note the file name is likely to be case sensitive

Comment: I have tried that path also, but no luck...

Comment: @Pekka웃 IE requests all `behavior:` URLs from the root directory, whether there is a leading slash or not.

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 PIE only recognises `border-radius`, without prefixes.

Add `border-radius: 10px` after the prefixed versions.

Comment: Also, `border-top-left-radius`, etc. should be removed.

Comment: ok thanks I will try when I get a moment, I'll come back and check your answer if it works!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
-webkite-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
```